# Where is Ubuntu source code?

Tags: source-code

How do I get the source code of the Ubuntu operating system?
How do I run the modified code?
What programming languages ​​can be used to modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the link to the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767821/how-do-i-get-the-ubuntu-source-code)

> The source code for ubuntu is divided up by package - from a running
>   ubuntu system you can easily retreive the source for any package by
>   doing:
>
> ```
> apt-get source (package name)
> ```
>
> Otherwise, go to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), and search up the package in question. For
>   example, here's the download page for the source code for a specific
>   version of curl:
>
> https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/7.21.2-4ubuntu1
>
> That said, it's a lot easier if you're on a Linux system already - the
>   package sources are divided into an original source tarball plus
>   ubuntu patches, so if you don't use `apt-get source`, you'll need to
>   manually apply the patch to the source code. And new-style packages
>   are even divided into multiple packages.
>
> What's more, the packages are generally not designed to be
>   cross-compiled from a non-Linux system. Even if you download them and
>   open them in VS, you won't be able to build them from a Windows
>   system.
>
> Finally, note that not everything is in C and C++ - there are packages
>   in just about any language you can imagine. But I suppose most of them
>   could be opened in VS as text files :)
>
> Note: If you really, **really** want all of it, and I can't stress enough
>   how silly it would be to download everything just to start learning
>   about the system, you can use the `debmirror` tool, available in ubuntu,
>   to do this:
>
> ```
> debmirror -a none \
>           --source \
>           -s main \
>           -d lucid,lucid-security,lucid-updates \
>           -r /ubuntu \ 
>           --progress \
>           -e http \
>           -h archive.ubuntu.com \ ## or other ubuntu archive mirror
>           destpath
> ```
>
> This will be an absolutely huge download. Have several tens of GBs of
>   space available. Note that this downloads only core packages - replace
>   `-s main` with `-s main,universe,multiverse,restricted` to get everything.
>
> Once you have the package files, you can extract the source by running
>   `dpkg-source -x` on a .dsc file of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some server of Debian/Ubuntu too into list of this file - before
you are able to use the command apt-get source  :

/etc/apt/sources.list

sources.list is explained in man of Ubuntu:

> man sources.list

Add into /etc/apt/sources.list (only in case it is not written already there)
after :

> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

this one line:

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  main restricted universe multiverse

Then after saving and closing gedit, do:

> sudo apt-get update

After this you should be able to use command with any package:

> sudo apt-get source

Cheers.